# How to Get the href attribute of the element using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, linktext, partiallinktext

Hello I want to get the Href link inside this HTML code but I couldn't I tried with the XPath but it just returns an error

The Xpath:

```
//*[@id="style_16076273510119000593_BODY"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/a
```

And here is the HTML code

```
<a type="Link" islinktobetracked="true" target="_blank" linkid="3f21f23defaf3c1dd21e27f700aaef7e" style="text-decoration:none;color:#ffffff !important;white-space: nowrap;" href="https://www.thewebsite.com/signin?" rel=" noopener noreferrer">Activate your account</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the value of the *href* attribute you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `link_text`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_link_text("Activate your account").get_attribute("href"))
  ```
- Using `partial_link_text`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Activate your account").get_attribute("href"))
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@type='Link' and text()='Activate your account']").get_attribute("href"))
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Activate your account"))).get_attribute("href"))
  ```
- Using `PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Activate your account"))).get_attribute("href"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@type='Link' and text()='Activate your account']"))).get_attribute("href"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```